# Qt compiler shows error while compiling on linux Machine

Tags: qt, qt4, qmake

My QT application have a plugin called "CinemasVisualizerPlugin" and while executing the line "setStyleSheet(styl);" its crashing

But the same code on other linux Machine its working. I suspect some path issue.

Any input wilbe very helpful. Thanks

```
    Debugging starts
    Plugin id: 3 V2 plguing id: 2
    Plugin id: 1 V2 plguing id: 2
    Plugin id: 3 V2 plguing id: 2
    Plugin name coming: "CinemasVisualizerPlugin"
    View mode plugin interface is enabled
    QObject::connect: Cannot connect ViewWindow::setCursorMode(ViewPanelCursorMode) to (null)::setCursorMode(ViewPanelCursorMode)
    QObject::connect: Cannot connect ViewWindow::restoreViewWindow() to (null)::restoreViewWindow()
    General Porp changed
    General Porp changed
    General Porp changed
    General Porp changed
    General Porp changed
    General Porp changed
    Value changed
    Text:X "1.000"
    Text:Y "0.000"
    Text:Z "1.000"
    Text:Dist "2.000"
    Text:X "1.000"
    Text:Y "0.700"
    Text:Z "1.000"
    Text:Dist "2.000"
    2d Lattice Porp changed
    2d Lattice Porp changed
    QObject::connect: No such signal csTwoSideButton::signalToolTabButtonSelected(bool) in ../CinemasVisualizerPlugin/Srcs/ViewerProperties/csMagneticMomentProperties.cpp:383
    QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'StyleComponent')
    QObject::connect: No such signal csTwoSideButton::signalToolTabButtonSelected(bool) in ../CinemasVisualizerPlugin/Srcs/ViewerProperties/csMagneticMomentProperties.cpp:384
    QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'StyleComponent')
    *** Error in `/home/embadmin/src_v3.0/build-Cinemas-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/Cinemas': double free or corruption (out): 0x000000000152dbe0 ***
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7ffff49747e5]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7ffff497d37a]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7ffff498153c]
    /home/embadmin/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN9QHashData11free_helperEPFvPNS_4NodeEE+0x54)[0x7ffff588b094]
    /home/embadmin/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN9QHashData11free_helperEPFvPNS_4NodeEE+0x49)[0x7ffff588b089]
    /home/embadmin/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5(+0x1ec86e)[0x7ffff6a5686e]
    /home/embadmin/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5(+0x1f6d13)[0x7ffff6a60d13]
    /home/embadmin/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5(+0x1f7056)[0x7ffff6a61056]
    /home/embadmin/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12inheritStyleEv+0x1b3)[0x7ffff69f5553]
    /home/embadmin/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate15setStyle_helperEP6QStylebb+0x1dd)[0x7ffff69f528d]
    /home/embadmin/src_v3.0/build-Cinemas-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/libCinemasVisualizerPluginD.so.1.0.0(_ZN21csMagMomentPropertiesC2EP7QWidget+0x735)[0x7fffe0180557]
    /home/embadmin/src_v3.0/build-Cinemas-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/libCinemasVisualizerPluginD.so.1.0.0(_ZN21csMagMomentProperties11getInstanceEv+0x30)[0x7fffe018363e]
    /home/embadmin/src_v3.0/build-Cinemas-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/libCinemasVisualizerPluginD.so.1.0.0(_ZN23csViewStyleOptionWidgetC2EP7QWidget+0x16f)[0x7fffe014d165]
    /home/embadmin/src_v3.0/build-Cinemas-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/libCinemasVisualizerPluginD.so.1.0.0(_ZN23csViewStyleOptionWidget11getInstanceEv+0x30)[0x7fffe014dd02]
    /home/embadmin/src_v3.0/build-Cinemas-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/libCinemasVisualizerPluginD.so.1.0.0(_ZN17StyleOptionWidgetC1EP7QWidget+0x108)[0x7fffe0152722]
    /home/embadmin/src_v3.0/build-Cinemas-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/libCinemasVisualizerPluginD.so.1.0.0(_ZN16csViewToolWindowC2EP7QWidget+0x1cf6)[0x7fffe0160e86]
    /home/embadmin/src_v3.0/build-Cinemas-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/libCinemasVisualizerPluginD.so.1.0.0(_ZN16csViewToolWindow11getInstanceEv+0x30)[0x7fffe016189a]
    /home/embadmin/src_v3.0/build-Cinemas-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/libCinemasVisualizerPluginD.so.1.0.0(_ZN16VisualizerWindowC2EP30CsCoreCentralModuleHandlerBase+0x114)[0x7fffe00b5d94]
    /home/embadmin/src_v3.0/build-Cinemas-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/libCinemasVisualizerPluginD.so.1.0.0(_ZN22VisualizerModulePlugin11addFeaturesERK7QStringP30CsCoreCentralModuleHandlerBase+0x111)[0x7fffe00b56b1]
```

Comment: Try `valgrind`, `gdb` and `rr`.

Comment: I didnt get you, u asking to change the compiler

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect some path issue.

Most probably it isn't. The error message reports a memory corruption

> double free or corruption (out): 0x000000000152dbe0

and the backtrace points to your custom code.

Velkans hint is correct, you should run the code in a debugger (`gdb`) and look at the backtrace to find the reason for the crash. If you can't find anything you need more advanced tools like `valgrind`.

If you don't know how to do that, learn it - it's a mandatory skill for every serious software developer, and you don't get very far without. Usually your IDE supports this and makes the usage rather comfortable; if not it's time to pick one that does.